# With subxt how can I subscribe to watch extrinsics?

Tags: rust, extrinsic, subxt

There's some great examples of how to use subxt to listen to [all events](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/examples/subscribe_all_events.rs).

Polkadot-js events screen seem to show events grouped by the extrinsic that created them. Can I do the same in rust?

(if not subxt is there an alternative way?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logic in subxt will map through in a similar way.

The [EventRecord struct](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6e740bc89d097a38d922d5619b55e0c7e8664a6c/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L706-L713) contains a [Phase enum](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6e740bc89d097a38d922d5619b55e0c7e8664a6c/frame/system/src/lib.rs#L688-L695) where `ApplyExtrinsic(u32)` refers to the index of the extrinsic in the block.

So the way to map it is -

1. If `phase` is not `ApplyExtrinsic`, it doesn't map to a transaction, e.g. it is a system event
2. If the `phase` is `ApplyExtrinsic`, get the index from this value
3. Map the extracted index to the extrinsic, as found in the block

Comment: Ah, that's what that number is in phase. The u32 is the extrinsic id (the transaction id). Great, now I just need to look up lots of extrinsic's by id...

Comment: Ah subxt can listen to blocks: `client.rpc().subscribe_blocks()` (but maybe we need to add that not uncommon usecase to the subxt examples!)

Comment: Thank you so much for getting me unstuck!