# How to get the extrinsics and their hash from a block with Subxt

Tags: subxt

How to get all extrinsics executed in a block with subxt?

My question is identical to [With subxt how can I subscribe to watch extrinsics?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2178/with-subxt-how-can-i-subscribe-to-watch-extrinsics)

> There's some great examples of how to use subxt to listen to [all
> events](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/examples/subscribe_all_events.rs).
>
> Polkadot-js events screen seem to show events grouped by the extrinsic
> that created them. Can I do the same in rust?

but the accepted answer [3](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2183/116) leaves me hanging at

> 3. Map the extracted index to the extrinsic, as found in the block

Where do I find this list of extrinsics in the block? Should I fetch the full block with a new rpc call like this?

```
let mut blocks: Subscription<Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>> =
    api.client.rpc().subscribe_blocks().await?;

while let Some(Ok(block)) = blocks.next().await {

    println!(
        "block number: {:?} hash:{:?} parent:{:?} state root:{:?} extrinsics root:{:?}",
        block.number,
        block.hash(),
        block.parent_hash,
        block.state_root,
        block.extrinsics_root
    ); 
    if let Ok(Some(fullblock)) = api.client.rpc().block(Some(block.hash())).await
        {             
        // block.
        for extr in fullblock.block.extrinsics {
               
            println!("Hello Extrinsics {:?}",extr);
        }
    }
}
```

if so what should I decode `extr:OpaqueExtrinsic` with the value `0401000ba5620d6d8201`

[image]

in to a type and encoded hash `0x8d5c44aba83278ee050e7595ba1e31ae9c0cc44ab4e02d0b55f83f07809556f3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing, the master branch of Subxt now supports asking for (recent) blocks and iterating over the extrinsics and their associated events; check out this example for more:

https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/33a9ec91afd16c459871e24ae18576f7afbb87c1/examples/examples/subscribe_blocks.rs

Essentially something like:

```rust
let block = api.blocks().at(block_hash).await?;
let body = block.body().await?;

for ext in body.extrinsics() {
    // print the bytes in each extrinsic:
    println!("0x{}", hex::encode(ext.bytes()));
}
```

This will give you back `0x` prefixed hex encoded bytes for each extrinsic in the block, which you can do as you wish with.

Answer (score 2):

`OpaqueExtrinsic` implements the trait `Encode` one could then use the `BlakeTwo256::hash_of()` function to calculate the hash value of the extrinsics.

```
use codec::Encode;

fn blake_two_256_hash<T>(data: T) -> H256
where
    T: Encode,
{
    let ans: H256 = BlakeTwo256::hash_of(&data);
    ans
}
```

And then fetch the full blocks as they are finalized:

```
let mut blocks: Subscription<Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>> =
    api.client.rpc().subscribe_blocks().await?;

while let Some(Ok(block)) = blocks.next().await {
    if let Ok(Some(fullblock)) = api.client.rpc().block(Some(block.hash())).await {
        for extr in fullblock.block.extrinsics {
           /// extr is an OpaqueExtrinsic
            println!("Got extrinsic Hash: {:?}",  blake_two_256_hash(&extr));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the libuptest crate to extract the extrinsic:
code example: https://uptest-sc.github.io/cli/event_sub.html#code-example